# Source File 'FilePathHere' could not be opened unspecified error .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to the .NET framework and was looking at a simple contact form that should submit an email when a button was clicked and am having issues.

Firstly, I started a new project (using master pages, if that matters) and changed changed the name of the default.aspx to SendMail.aspx.  Then, I just copied and pasted the code into the project I created.

I get multiple errors and warnings in the mark up of SendMail telling me that, for example `'Element' Button is not a known element.  This can occur if there is a compilation error in the web site for the web.config file is missing`.  The web.config file is not missing.  However, I get a warning on this for every asp control on the page

I also get a compiler error Which tells me that the source file could not be opened.  The compiler then lists the file path with the name Default.aspx.cs.  This is the name of the file that I changed in Visual Studio, and yet the compiler is still trying to read that file name.

What's going on here so I can fix these problems in the future?

markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="SendMail.aspx.cs" Inherits="SmtpExample._Default" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSubmit">
    <p>
        Please Fill the Following to Send Mail.</p>
    <p>
        Your name:
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator11" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
            ControlToValidate="YourName" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="YourName" runat="server" Width="250px" /><br />
        Your email address:
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
            ControlToValidate="YourEmail" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="YourEmail" runat="server" Width="250px" />
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ID="RegularExpressionValidator23"
            SetFocusOnError="true" Text="Example: username@gmail.com" ControlToValidate="YourEmail"
            ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Display="Dynamic"
            ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
        Subject:
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
            ControlToValidate="YourSubject" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="YourSubject" runat="server" Width="400px" /><br />
        Your Question:
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*"
            ControlToValidate="Comments" ValidationGroup="save" /><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="Comments" runat="server" 
                TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="10" Width="400px" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send" 
                    OnClick="Button1_Click" ValidationGroup="save" />
    </p>
</asp:Panel>
<p>
    <asp:Label ID="DisplayMessage" runat="server" Visible="false" />
</p>  
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="MainContent">
</asp:Content>
```

code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace SmtpExample
{
    public partial class _SendMail : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        protected void SendMail()
        {
            // Gmail Address from where you send the mail
            var fromAddress = "Gmail@gmail.com";
            // any address where the email will be sending
            var toAddress = YourEmail.Text.ToString();
            //Password of your gmail address
            const string fromPassword = "Password";
            // Passing the values and make a email formate to display
            string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
            string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
            body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
            body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
            body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";
            // smtp settings
            var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
            {
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress, fromPassword);
                smtp.Timeout = 20000;
            }
            // Passing values to smtp object
            smtp.Send(fromAddress, toAddress, subject, body);
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //here on button click what will done 
                SendMail();
                DisplayMessage.Text = "Your Comments after sending the mail";
                DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
                YourSubject.Text = "";
                YourEmail.Text = "";
                YourName.Text = "";
                Comments.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are placing elements in ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" it must be in contentplaceholderid="MainContent"

> update

i see you rename the default.aspx file to send SendMail.aspx that will throe error from partial classes default.aspx.cs and default.aspx.design.cs. do this create new page SendMail.aspx and copy your code to ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent", right click on page i solution explorer  click on set as start page

Comment: That helps with the recognition of the controls, but not with why the compiler is trying use the old file name for the code behind.